# Is it possible to stream a live flash video on iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, flash, stream

If you go on http://www.africam.com/wildlife/tembe_webcam you can see theirs a live video stream in flash format. I need to know if it's possible to play that live stream on the iPhone.
And if possible, is there any API I need to know about?

Comment: Is Africam yours or are you just wanting to use the feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes FMS 4.5 supprts streaming to iOS http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-media-streaming.html

You can tryout AWS FMS 5 pay-as-you-go http://www.adobe.com/products/amazon-web-services.html

Edit: Also you have the http://www.wowza.com/

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are these APIs, or seperate programs? (I program in objective c on a mac, the fms download is only for windows and linux)

Comment: FMS is installed on the server. Then you use API to stream TO and FROM the server.